# How can I get my scripts to update using Unity 2017.3.1f1 and Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I am using Unity 2017.3.1f1 and Visual Studio 2017 to edit my scripts, but when I save them in visual studio they do not update in Unity and use the old scripts instead. I have tried refreshing my assets, deleting the ScriptAssemblies folder, but nothing has worked. Please help!

Comment: you could try copying assets and projectsettings folders to a different folder and opening that folder as a project(or deleting the "library" and temp folders and the .csproj files).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try closing unity and vs, restarting unity and opening the vs solution by double clicking any script, make sure to clean your solution and then build your solution.

Also perhaps clear the NuGet cache and then restore the dependencies for your solution.

I've had some similar issues and this usually just requires some relaunching a couple times and repeating a clean, build, nuget restore process until everything is working properly.